# Prove $P(\mathbb{R})\subset C(\mathbb{R}))$ is dependent, $ C(\mathbb{R}))$ contains all continous functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I know I can represent a polynomial as: $$P_n(\mathbb{R})=a_0 x^{n} + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n$$
I want to find if this has only one solution or not: $$C_1P_1(x)+C_2P_2(x)+\dots+C_nP_n(x)=0$$
From this I can deduce a general matrix of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}c_{11}+c_{12}+\dots+c_{1n}& 0\\\dots\\c_{m1}+c_{m2}+\dots+c_{mn} &0\end{bmatrix}$$

After that I'm lost on how I can prove this set of equations can be determined if they have or not a unique solution. I'd like to know If my reasoning is correct or if I'm missing something more essential.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you're trying to ask here.  To the best of my understanding, you're asking something like *"given $n$ polynomials $P_1, \dots, P_n$, how can we check whether these polynomials are linearly independent?"*

Comment: Sorry If it's not clear enough, but yes that's what I'm asking.